# Quasi-transitive decomposition of a transitive graph

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple digraph that is semi-complete (ie. there's at least one arc between each unordered pair of vertices) and quasi-transitive (ie. its complement is transitive).

Is it true that we can decompose $G$ into semi-complete, transitive spanning subgraphs? In other words, is there a collection of graphs $G_n=(V,E_n)$ where $G_n$ is semi-complete and transitive and $E=\bigcup_n E_n$?

Note that the union of the edges needn't be disjoint. In case it makes a difference, I'm particularly curious about the case where $V$ is infinite.

Thanks!

Comment: your terminology is strange; typically, "simple" means that there are no multiple arcs. If we assume that, then the digraphs in question are called tournaments, and are well-studied.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusing terminology, I meant that there can be at most one edge from $x$ to $y$, but unlike a tournament, perhaps one from $y$ to $x$ as well.

Comment: the union of edges of $G_n$'s certainly cannot always be disjoint (take a tournament and add one more arc somewhere).

Comment: It's also not clear what you mean by quasi-transitive: "complement" usually means that edges and non-edges replace each other.

Comment: That is what I mean--a graph would be quasi-transitive if $(x,y)\not in E$ and $(y,z)\notin E$ imply $(x,z)\notin E$ for all $x,y,z\in V$.

Comment: I don't see how such a decomposition would look like for the directed 3-cycle with one extra arc $a$. It seems to impossible to put $a$ into a $G_i$ in the decomposition.

Comment: A decomposition shouldn't exist, $G$ complement is a 3-cycle with one edge missing so $G$ is not pseudo-transitive.

Comment: If I read the conditions correctly, the complement of $G$ is required to be a partial order, and the complements of the $G_n$ are linear orders, hence you are asking whether every partial order is an intersection of linear orders. This is indeed true.

Comment: Emil, this answers my question. Thank you very much.